# Open Windows Explorer from VB.NET: doesn't open in the right folder

Tags: vb.net, process, explorer

I am trying to locate a file from a program, in VB.NET

```
Dim exeName As String = "explorer.exe"
Dim params As String = "/e,""c:\test"",/select,""C:\test\a.txt""" 
Dim processInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(exeName, params)
Process.Start(processInfo)
```

It opens the containing directory "c:\" but doesn't go inside to "c:\test", I would like to have the file selected...

Comment: Your code worked for me. Are you sure `C:\test` and `C:\test\a.txt` actually exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the folder path in there after the /e, try this for your params:

```
Dim params As String = "/e, /select,""C:\temp\file.txt"""
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim filePath As String = "C:\test\a.txt" 'Example file
 Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select," & filePath) 'Starts explorer.exe and selects desired file
```